# django registration and saving data

Tags: django, profile, django-registration

ok i've got ask again.

I'm using django-registration this time with a backend to help me.

If anyone is curious as to why my regbackend.py has so many other functions, that's cos the server was complaining about those methods so i just copied and pasted there.

However, i would just like to know how does the backend call the save function that will save it in the database.

I've included the save method here because i thought it would be called here. Otherwise it's already in my forms.py.

Please do help me, i've actually tried looking at pinax and django profiles but that would require a whole revamp of my project.

Thank you so much.

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from r2.models import Keyword
from r2.models import UserProfile
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from registration.models import RegistrationProfile
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm, attrs_dict

class ProjectSpecificRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    keywords = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Keyword.objects.all())
    first_name =forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),label=_(u'First Name')) 
    last_name =forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),label=_(u'Last Name'))

    def save(self, profile_callback=None):
        new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
        password=self.cleaned_data['password1'],
        email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
    new_profile = UserProfile(user=new_user,username=self.cleaned_data['username'], keywords_subscribed=self.cleaned_data['keywords'],first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'],last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name'])

        new_profile.save()
        return new_user()
```

**Urls.py:**

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$',register, {'backend': 'registration.regbackend.RegBackend','form_class' : ProjectSpecificRegistrationForm},  name='registration_register'),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

Here is my **regbackend.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from registration import signals
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from registration.models import RegistrationProfile
from r2.forms import ProjectSpecificRegistrationForm
from r2.models import *

class RegBackend(object):

    def register(self, request, **kwargs):

        username, email, password = kwargs['username'], kwargs['email'], kwargs['password1']
        if Site._meta.installed:
            site = Site.objects.get_current()
        else:
            site = RequestSite(request)
        new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email,
                                                                    password, site)
    user = User.objects.get(username=new_user.username)
        user.first_name = kwargs['first_name']
        user.last_name = kwargs['last_name']
    user.keywords = kwargs['keywords']

        signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__, user=new_user, request=request)
    user.save() 
        return new_user

    def save(self, profile_callback=None):
        print('Came in')
        new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
        password=self.cleaned_data['password1'],
        email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
    new_profile = UserProfile(user=new_user,username=self.cleaned_data['username'], keywords_subscribed=self.cleaned_data['keywords'],first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'],last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name'])

        new_profile.save()
        return new_user()

    def registration_allowed(self, request):
        return getattr(settings, 'REGISTRATION_OPEN', True)

    def post_registration_redirect(self, request, user):
        return ('registration_complete', (), {})
```

Comment: Intendation seems incorrect to me.

Answer (score 1):

To create new user you should use `register` method of your backend. You will need to pass `request` there, so it should be called from the view (or other place that have access to `request`)

```
backend = RegBackend()
user = backend.register(request, **your_kwargs)
```

> the server was complaining about those methods so i just copied and pasted there.

No need to copy anything, just use inheritance (from `registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend`)

And registration backend doesn't (and shouldn't) have `save` method.

Comment: ah that makes sense. Alright let me try it out! thanks DrTyrsa!

Comment: actually it's already using my register method of my backend. I've printed some lines and the console prints it out. What i can't get it to do is to save in my database @DrTyrsa

Comment: @StanwinSiow Check your intendation. And if you want to add some `keywords`, do it in `register` method, `save` method won't be called.